# FCM getToken() Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope error Flutter web

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-web

In my app, for the web version, I use package `firebase 7.3.0`.
I first instantiate Firebase app with a singleton and then instantiate Messaging() as I have done with all other Firebase services I use in my app :

```
App firebase = FirebaseWeb.instance.app;
  var firebaseMessaging = messaging();
```

I have `subscribeToTopic()` method which first calls `getMessagingToken()` method as it needs the returned token, but `getMessagingToken()` throws the error:

```
PlatformPushNotificationWeb.getMessagingToken() getToken error: FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:5000/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:5000/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration). (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration)
```

```
Future<String> getMessagingToken() async {
    String token;

    await firebaseMessaging.requestPermission().timeout(Duration(seconds: 5)).then((value) {
      print('PlatformPushNotificationWeb.getMessagingToken() requestPermission result is $value');
    }).catchError((e) => print('PlatformPushNotificationWeb.getMessagingToken() requestPermission error: $e'));

    await firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((value) {
      print(' PlatformPushNotificationWeb.getMessagingToken() token is $value');
      token = value;
    }).catchError((e) => print('PlatformPushNotificationWeb.getMessagingToken() getToken error: $e'));

    return token;
  }
```

I checked and in my `index.html` firebase-messaging is present:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>fixit cloud biking</title>
  <!--  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">-->
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<!--  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">-->
</head>
<!--<body>-->
<body id="app-container">
<script src="main.dart.js?version=45" type="application/javascript"></script>
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-remote-config.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, the error says `'http://localhost:5000/firebase-messaging-sw.js'` not `firebase-messaging.js` as the library in the index.html`file.  I noticed that` Messaging()`is not directly available through firebase app instance as it would be for other services, for Storage would be`firebase.storage()`.
Am I missing to setup something else for messaging?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Found this article https://medium.com/@rody.davis.jr/how-to-send-push-notifications-on-flutter-web-fcm-b3e64f1e2b76 and discovered that indeed there is a bit more setup for Firebase Cloud Messaging on web.

In `index.html` there is a script to add:

```
<script>
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    // navigator.serviceWorker.register("/flutter_service_worker.js");
    navigator.serviceWorker.register("/firebase-messaging-sw.js");
  });
}
</script>
```

In project `web` folder create a new file `firebase-messaging-sw.js` where you import the firebase packages (match `index.html` versions), initialize Firebase app , and set the BackgroundMessageHandler.
If I initialize Firebase app with the singleton then instantiating `messaging()` throws a syntax error, so it needs to be initialized with all parameters, otherwise on background messages won't work.

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-app.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-messaging.js");

//Using singleton breaks instantiating messaging()
// App firebase = FirebaseWeb.instance.app;


firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: 'api-key',
  authDomain: 'project-id.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://project-id.firebaseio.com',
  projectId: 'project-id',
  storageBucket: 'project-id.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: 'sender-id',
  appId: 'app-id',
  measurementId: 'G-measurement-id',
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
    const promiseChain = clients
        .matchAll({
            type: "window",
            includeUncontrolled: true
        })
        .then(windowClients => {
            for (let i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
                const windowClient = windowClients[i];
                windowClient.postMessage(payload);
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            return registration.showNotification("New Message");
        });
    return promiseChain;
});
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
    console.log('notification received: ', event)
});
```

So now, `getToken()` and `subscribeToTopic()` and `onMessage()` work as expected.

In my bloc I have a listener on `onMessage()` which (on web) Stream I convert to a `Stream<Map<String,Dynamic>>` as the `firebase_messaging`(on device) returns from :

```
Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> onMessage()  async* {

    print('PlatformPushNotificationWeb.onMessage() started');
    handleData(Payload payload, EventSink<Map<String, dynamic>> sink) {
        Map<String,dynamic> message = {
          'notification': {
            'title': payload.notification.title,
            'body': payload.notification.body,
            'sound': true
          },
          'data': payload.data
        };
      sink.add(message);
    }

    final transformer = StreamTransformer<Payload, Map<String, dynamic>>.fromHandlers(
        handleData: handleData);

    yield* firebaseMessaging.onMessage.transform(transformer);
  }
```

Hope it helps others.
Cheers.

**CAUTION**: In an official release, note that your service worker is visible in the browser, which means this solution will expose your API keys and, any other sensitive data, to the world. For example, you can press F12 to open developer options and view the service worker file.

- For moderate protection, you may store the firebase configuration in environment variables. Though, I would recommend encrypting them if you do this.
- For a higher level of protection, one solution is to use cloud secret manager to store keys, where google provides encryption. I would recommend requiring the Admin sdk to obtain the 'secret' with a cloud function.
- For best security, rotate any sensitive keys at some interval, and store them somewhere that they can be encrypted. Again, encryption is automatically done for you when using the google cloud secret manager.
- When the code is completed, a minifier can be used to reduce your code as well, which is very helpful for security.

Comment: Thank you for this response, this solved my problem as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66867680/flutter-failed-to-register-a-serviceworker-for-scope-with-script-the-script-has

Comment: This answer should be wayyy upvoted. This solved it for me too. Cheers

Comment: Glad it helped. I struglled quite a bit with it. Now with thre latest official packages versions supporting web I switched to only those packs. Thanks for the comment. Cheers.

Comment: this answer should have 1000 upvotes. Is the ONLY solution I could find online.

Comment: @Mariano Zorrilla . So glad that it could help you. Indeed when I had the problem I couldn't find almost anything on the subject.

Comment: this solution works very well for me !! ty!!

Comment: Where does that Stream bloc should reside? What is the Payload type?

Comment: if commenting out `navigator.serviceWorker.register("/flutter_service_worker.js");` site doesn't load, it's there for a reason

Comment: Having your apiKey public is fine. It is not a secret key. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public) for more details.

Comment: @FoxDonut thanks for the edits, you did add a very important part to it.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out you can just create a file called `firebase-messaging-sw.js` in your web project folder and have some commented out JavaScript in it and then Flutter stops complaining.

Also modify index.html with this:

```
<script>
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register("firebase-messaging-sw.js");
  });

  window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
  });
}
```

I really don't know why this works, but it's better than having some useless JavaScript code laying around.

Comment: This approach gives me the error: “Uncaught (in promise) Error: AbortError: Failed to execute 'subscribe' on 'PushManager': Subscription failed - no active Service Worker” 
when I try to call "fcmToken = await messaging.getToken();"

Answer (score 3):

As of December 2022, just creating an empty `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file at the root of the `web` directory in your flutter app will fix the issue.

---

Before that you of course follow the steps to add Firebase to your app: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup

> `dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli`
> `flutterfire configure`

Then

> In your lib/main.dart file, import the Firebase core plugin and the configuration file you generated earlier:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
```

Finally

> Also in your lib/main.dart file, initialize Firebase using the DefaultFirebaseOptions object exported by the configuration file:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for answering, what a coincidence!! I'm going through the problem again, after upgrading to latest Flutter, does it have to do with it?

Comment: It's possible, in any case I am using the latest version of Flutter and it worked like this. Note that you need to use flutterfire configure to make it work correctly, see my edit.

Comment: I'm just about getting rid of firebase altogether. Since I started using it I only had to put up with be like this. They keep updating their code either with new naming  which change from including to not including "firebase" or "Firebase" ..I first git rid of their db for the stupidity. Not being able to query for range on more than one parameter. Forcing to do two different queries an filter out returned data... Of course .. so they chan charge you more document reads.. so I put up a node server with MongoDb and  only use their auth and messaging nowadays.

Comment: So ai already put the subscribe/unsubscribe to topics part in it and I'll put all the rest of the messaging functions there an leave just bare https calls from my apps. Al least this way I don't have to put up with so much refactoring every time their developers wake up with some brilliant idea about renaming thing.. I guess they have so much useless people that have to justify their salary somehow. When you see continuous  bs like this usually this is the reason.

Comment: As a matter of fact after believing so much in Flutter I'm about to switch to React. So many problems with the plugins.. jeez I could understand them at v.1.0 but not anymore..production ready my...I really do dislike markup languages and that's why I never been into web developing..but I really guess it's time to make pace with it and make the switch to an actual production ready system.

Comment: I also keep the bare minimum. Problem is that Apple and Google have monopoly when it comes to push notification since they are the only one that can push app notification while an app is terminated.

Flutter Web is still very new but I have seen the incredible development in the past 2 years. For client I use Flutter and for server Nodejs express.

Comment: Same as me. Do you send pushes from device with the sdk or do you send them from the server? I'm thinking to switch to handle push notifications completely from the server as I just had to add the subscribe/unsubscribe methods.

Comment: I send them initially from the client side as Admin to the server which then pushes it back to the client devices. I don't use topic as it is not supported for Flutter Web. (I also use flutter web as a client for those who don't get the app).

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL how to  register firebase-messaging-sw.js in Index.html

Comment: This approach gives me the error: “A bad HTTP response code (500) was received when fetching the script. errors.dart:327 Uncaught (in promise) Error: FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker” 
when I attempt to call "fcmToken = await messaging.getToken();"

Comment: @Turkey do you had success on this? I got same error.