# Flutter Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope with script, The script has an unsupported MIME type

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a fully functioning Flutter app with FlutterFire, where the android bundle works just fine, but the web client gives a strange error upon start. I cannot call any firebase function with flutterfire with it either. (simple firebase queries works just fine)

The error message upon startup or when I try to call `FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallabe('...`:

```
:1337/dart_sdk.js:7025 Uncaught (in promise) Error: [firebase_messaging/failed-service-worker-registration] Messaging: 
We are unable to register the default service worker. 
Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:1337/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:1337/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html'). .
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (:1337/dart_sdk.js:5334)
    at firebase_messaging_web.FirebaseMessagingWeb.new.getToken (:1337/packages/firebase_messaging_web/firebase_messaging_web.dart.lib.js:112)
    at getToken.throw (<anonymous>)
    at :1337/dart_sdk.js:39038
    at _RootZone.runBinary (:1337/dart_sdk.js:38894)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleError (:1337/dart_sdk.js:33887)
    at handleError (:1337/dart_sdk.js:34451)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (:1337/dart_sdk.js:34477)
    at _Future.new.[_completeError] (:1337/dart_sdk.js:34323)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (:1337/dart_sdk.js:34362)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (:1337/dart_sdk.js:39176)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (:1337/dart_sdk.js:39182)
    at :1337/dart_sdk.js:34689
```

**I don't have a firebase-messaging-sw.js** file.  I only did what the documentation recommended https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/#5-web-only-add-the-sdk.

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...

  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-functions.js"></script>


  <script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "****",
      authDomain: "*****",
      databaseURL: "*****",
      projectId: "*****",
      storageBucket: "*****",
      messagingSenderId: "*****",
      appId: "*****"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<script >
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
    });
  }
</script>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Flutter doctor:

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.3, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63800226/3486691

I had to create the file and provide the default settings so the app can work without throwing errors.