# Error: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

My Flutter app on web has been using Firebase Cloud Messaging for a long time without error.  Today, with no changes, it is giving the following error:

> Error: [firebase_messaging/failed-service-worker-registration] Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:50093/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:50093/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): The Service Worker system has shutdown.

Can anyone explain why this error is occurring now?  I suspect something must have changed on Firebase's end, because my code has not changed.

Comment: Check this github page: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/229

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an older version of Firebase Cloud Messaging plugin, you might need to follow this [setup guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63800226) to create a default app settings for web. On current version of FCM, you can follow this [initialization guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios#add-plugins) to add the FCM plugin on your app.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by adding `firebase-messaging-sw.js` under **web** directory like the image below

[image: image of adding a file named firebase-messaging-sw.js under web directory]

Also implementing the code below:

```js
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register('../firebase-messaging-sw.js')
    .then(function (registration) {
      console.log('Registration successful, scope is:', registration.scope)
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log('Service worker registration failed, error:', err)
    })
}
```