# Flutter Firebase Notification on Web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-notification

In my flutter project, I already have notifications set up using firebase_messaging for Android and iOS. I am trying to add the same for Web. I had tried it before (mostly changing index.html with firebase-configs and initializing), but it had not worked then and I had left it. Now [their document asks](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation/web/) to use the new way, which asks only to [configure it in the dart-](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=web)files, and talks nothing about doing anything on index or other js files. So I have removed imports, and initialization from `index.html`, and not added any other file ( I have tried adding empty `firebase-messaging-sw.js` and removing it). This is the error I am getting:

```
[firebase_messaging/failed-service-worker-registration] Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:44055/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:44055/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. .
```

What am I missing? Are those steps incomplete? I also tried the steps in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63799227/fcm-gettoken-failed-to-register-a-serviceworker-for-scope-error-flutter-web/63800226#63800226) , but still have the same issues.

**Edit**
These are all the code-parts related to firebase-messaging.

```
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
    firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;
    firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance; //

    final notificationSettings = await firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();
    debugPrint('User granted permission: ${notificationSettings.authorizationStatus}');
    
    if (!kIsWeb) {
      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(
          _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
      channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
        'high_importance_channel', // id
        'High Importance Notifications', // title
        description: 'This channel is used for important notifications.',
        // description
        importance: Importance.max,
      );
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

      /// Create an Android Notification Channel.
      ///
      /// We use this channel in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file to override the
      /// default FCM channel to enable heads up notifications.
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
          .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

      /// Update the iOS foreground notification presentation options to allow
      /// heads up notifications.
      await FirebaseMessaging.instance
          .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
      );
    }
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
    if (kIsWeb) {
     // this is where the code throws error: 
      token = (await firebaseMessaging.getToken(
        vapidKey: "BLn....pH8",
      ))!;
    } else {
      token = (await firebaseMessaging.getToken())!;
    }
```